# Deleting record in sharepoint list

Tags: sharepoint, list, caml

I want to delete records in list view in sharepoint. This should only be a logical delete the actual data itself should not be deleted . How to accomplish thsi ?
Please suggest

Answer (score 3):

Without going much on why you want to do that, here's an idea:

You could create a filter based in a column, say, A Yes/No Column named "Hide From View" and on the Filter options in the Modify View Settings you choose to not display items that are not equal to your Hide From View column.

- Create new Yes/No Column, name: HideFromView, default value: No
- Edit/Modify the View, go to the "Filter" group
- Select the option: **Show items only when the following is true**
- Configure with:

  - Show the items when column "HideFromView"
  - Is Equal To
  - No
- Edit your list items and mark a few Checkboxes for this column.
- You now have a filtered list, without actually deleting the data

Comment: that look a good solution . but can you provide more details with an example would be nice 
thanks

Comment: We typically do something similar, which is having an Active/Archived value which we filter on in CAML queries.

Answer (score 1):

Another option is to set the item's permissions to be only visible to / editable by Site Collection Administrators. Anyone who is not a site collection admin will not see the item when viewing the list. This way only the site collection admins are allowed to really delete / edit those items later, when they really aren't needed anymore, or restore the permissions if the item needs to be visible to other users again.

Read more on how to change permissions on items, folders, lists etc.  here: [Manage permissions for a list, library, folder, document, or list item](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepointserver/HA100215641033.aspx). 
Look under the "Break permission inheritance on a folder, document, or list item" paragraph.

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to simply move the items to another list.